# Need to get the array of vertices and faces using three.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, visualization, gltf

This is what I have currently.

```
 return from(fetch(targetUrl.toString(), {headers: { 'responseType': 'application/octet-stream'}, method: 'GET'})).pipe(
            map((surfaceMesh) => {
                this.surfaceMeshes.set(surfaceMeshKey, surfaceMesh);
            }
        )
```

Previously, the server response was in JSON providing so everything worked perfectly. The previous response looked somewhat like this.

```
content_uncompressed = {
            "api_info": f"Visualization REST Server {__version__}",
            "component_id": component_id_int,
            "vertices": vertex_list,
            "faces": trig_faces.tolist(),
            "n_faces": n_trig_faces,
        }
```

However, recently, the server response has been changed to an octet-stream (that kind for .glb file). So of course, the array of vertices and faces are no longer available. I was wondering how do I extract the vertices and faces and put it in two different arrays in my return statement using GLTF Loader of three.js (or anything else). It would mean a lot to me if you write the code down for me as I am very new to all this.

Comment: I feel like this question needs a lot more information. Why did the server response change? What response do you get now? Did this change happen on its own? Are you in charge of this server? You're not even showing us what file type you're trying to fetch. There are too many unanswered questions to help you.

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you so much for your comment. I apologise for the less information. To clarify, I changed the server response to an octet stream because that was part of the task assigned. The type of file that's being sent is an 'octet-stream'. It's basically a glb file and I need to use.